# Trigger AJAX update after value insert using window.opener.document.getElementById(formId).value

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsf, primefaces

I have a form where the user has to enter an Employee's Identification (badge) Number. Employee is a POJO with badge number as the primary key. They can type the badge number in but if they don't know a person's id, I provide a button next to the input text box that pops open another form where the user can search on any employee data to find the correct badge number. They can click the badge number and javascript pastes this value into the parent form using.

```
function selectCode(pasteValue, formId) {
window.opener.document.getElementById(formId).value = pasteValue;
self.close();
}
```

But this event doesn't fire my AJAX event in the parent form which in supposed to display the employee's name and department below the badge number text input box in this facelets snippet.

```
<h:outputText value="Manager :"/>
   <h:panelGroup>
     <h:outputText value="Badge "/>
     <p:inputText id="managerBadge" title="Type a badge or click the Badge Finder Button to search Employees" value="#{bean.dept.manager}" required="false" converter="#{employeeConverter}">
     <p:ajax update="@form" /></p:inputText>&nbsp;
     <p:button onclick="open_finder(this.form.id, 'managerBadge', 'findBadge'); return false;" value="Badge Finder" title="Click to Open Badge Finder" />
     <br />
     <h:outputText id="manager" value="#{bean.dept.manager.fname} #{bean.dept.manager.lname} Dept: #{bean.dept.manager.home_dept_number}"/>
   </h:panelGroup>
<p:message for="managerBadge" />
```

The AJAX fires when the badge is typed into the box and the persons name is displayed as expected.  Here is a screen shot.  In the Manager box, I typed ABC123 and my name and dept shows below as expected.  But when I use the badge finder as I did with the Supervisor box, the form is not updated and I do not see my name and department displayed below the input box.

I've tried a few other AJAX events on the Primefaces p:ajax tag but no luck.  I also tried switching gears to using the p:autocomplete for Employee fields but those issues may call for another SO question post.

[image]

Comment: `document.getElementById(formId).value` you set value for a form instead of an input? You can do `console.log()` at he the end of `selectCode` and debug if value was really set or even check console for errors (element with id ... was not found etc.). Aside logical errors, since you use PrimeFaces then you can use jQuery for triggerring events manually `$("#formINput").trigger("change")`.

Comment: it gets set.  formId is a misnomer.  It is not the id of the form but the id of the input in the form.  I should rename the variable to component id or something.